# How to cast variable type from table of class types

Tags: java, casting, mapping

I have a typeMap

```
    Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

            typeMap.put("x", Integer.class);
            typeMap.put("y", Integer.class);
            typeMap.put("f", Float.class);
            typeMap.put("p", Integer.class);

    String values[]={"3","24.3"}
```

how can I do something like:

```
int x = (typeMap.get("x"))value[0];
float y= (typeMap.get("f"))value[1];
```

Comment: The only value I see in being able to accomplish this is if there is some mapping between the array element and the key of the map.  Does such a mapping exist?

Comment: can be , how can i get it accomplished

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access HashMap elements by index.
You access them by key. This is a fundamental thing.

So `typeMap.get(0)` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implicitly cast a String into a number type. You would have to parse it. Thus you should use Integer.parse(), Long.parse(), Double.parse() and so on.